# Why I receive "Unable to locate credentials" while using 'requests_ip_rotator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, session, python-requests

I try to use `requests_ip_rotator` library ([doc](https://github.com/Ge0rg3/requests-ip-rotator)) but don't know why I receive `Unable to locate credentials`

**The code I use:**

```py
import requests
from requests_ip_rotator import ApiGateway

gateway = ApiGateway('https://api.github.com')
gateway.start(force=True)  # Error comes from here!!!

session = requests.Session()
session.mount("https://api.github.com", gateway)
session.get("https://api.github.com/users/amir-shamsi")
```

**Error I got:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\dev-test-dir\dev-test.py", line 5, in <module>
    gateway.start(force=True)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\requests_ip_rotator\ip_rotator.py", line 259, in start
    result = future.result()
  File "D:\Data\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\Data\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\Data\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\requests_ip_rotator\ip_rotator.py", line 105, in init_gateway
    create_api_response = awsclient.create_rest_api(
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 415, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 731, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 751, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 107, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 180, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 120, in create_request
    self._event_emitter.emit(event_name, request=request,
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 358, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 229, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 212, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 95, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 167, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "D:\test\interpreters\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 401, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you read [that doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)?